# Reindex ElasticSearch index returns "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_reindex] and method [GET], allowed: [POST]"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to upgrade an elasticsearch cluster from 1.x to 6.x.  I'm reindexing the remote 1.x indices into the 6.x cluster.  According to [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html#reindex-upgrade-remote), this is possible:

> To upgrade an Elasticsearch 1.x cluster, you have two options:
>
> - Perform a full cluster restart upgrade to Elasticsearch 2.4.x and reindex or delete the 1.x indices. Then, perform a full cluster restart upgrade to 5.6 and reindex or delete the 2.x indices. Finally, perform a rolling upgrade to 6.x. For more information about upgrading from 1.x to 2.4, see Upgrading Elasticsearch in the Elasticsearch 2.4 Reference. For more information about upgrading from 2.4 to 5.6, see Upgrading Elasticsearch in the Elasticsearch 5.6 Reference.
> - **Create a new 6.x cluster and reindex from remote to import indices directly from the 1.x cluster.**

I'm doing this locally for test purposes, and using the following command with 6.x running:

```
curl --request POST localhost:9200/_reindex -d @reindex.json
```

My reindex.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://localhost:9200"
    },
    "index": "some_index_name",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "test": "data"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "some_index_name"
  }
}
```

However, this returns the following error:

> Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_reindex] and method [GET], allowed: [POST]"

Why is it telling me I can't use GET and to use POST instead?  I'm clearly specifying a POST request here, but it seems to think it's a GET request.  Any idea why it's getting the wrong request type?

Comment: try this instead `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_reindex --data-binary @reindex.json`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but by adding setting in the PUT request it worked.

```
PUT /my_blog
{
  "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
  },
    "mapping": {
        "post": {
            "properties": {
                "user_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "post_text": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "post_date": {
                    "type": "date"
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also refer this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html